# Watching process state transition

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel

I need to write linux application that will monitor specified process. Is it possible to be informed about every change of process state? I mean every change of field `state` in `task_struct`

Comment: ***[Look here...](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/153873-getting-task_struct-process-using-its-pid.html)***  Read down to the last two or three posts, they are talking about what you want to do.

Comment: They are talking about getting **current** information about process. I want not just get info about current state, but being informed when it changes. For example, when process changes it's status from TASK_RUNNING to TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE.

Comment: Such info is only good for a few nanoseconds, then it's stale.

Comment: Well, yes. Mentioned program is an university project, and don't have to be useful in real life. Information about state transition would be used only to generate plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enable ftrace and keep logging it

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace
cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on 
1
cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/current_tracer 
function
cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_tracers 
blk function_graph mmiotrace wakeup_rt wakeup function nop
```

Follow: http://lwn.net/Articles/290277/

Comment: Thanks! `trace-cmd record -e sched:sched_switch` is what I needed